# How do I update Google play services when I can't open the play store

Tags: google-play-store

I didnt update my Google play services and now I can't open any apps that needs play services

Comment: Google Play services should update automatically in the background, you don't need to do anything. Connect to WiFi or a good mobile data signal and wait a while and try the store again later.

Comment: Or, if you are brave, it is available by direct download from APKmirror. (I usually trust these especially since the link is given via AndroidPolice.com). This is the last article I can find at AndroidPolice where Google Play services was newly [uploaded](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/06/13/google-play-services-v9-2-adds-support-for-all-of-the-new-nearby-capabilities-and-likely-includes-peer-to-peer-file-transfer-apk-download-teardown/)

Comment: You can easily download a package of a newer version from a 3rd party source and install it directly. It's safe to do so as Android surely doesn't allow a modified package to be installed as an update (signature mismatch).